# Replace specified text from index to another index in array python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to replace a searched text in an array from a specified element to another specified element in this array.
I know there is a “replace” function but it will replace all the occurrences of that searched field. So I want to know if there is another function or another trick that can do what I want
Like this:

```
myarray = ["time (1)",
"the text to replace ",
"time (2)",
"the text to replace ",
"time (3)",
"the text to replace ",
"time (4)",
"the text to replace ",
"time (5)",
"the text to replace ",
"time (6)",
"the text to replace ",
"time (7)",
"the text to replace ",
"time (8)",
"the text to replace ",
"time (9)",
"the text to replace ",
"time (10)",
"the text to replace "]

myfunc(4,8)

def myfunc(fromtime, totime):
    for line in myarray
    #find the time from (fromtime) to (totime) and replace 'text' with 'string' for example
    print myarray
```

Can any one help me? Please! Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to replace it to? can you give us your desired output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with what you've tried and your desired output. Are the elements in your list (note that this is a `list`, not an `array`) actually the _word_ "time", or are they actual timestamps?

Comment: @G.Anderson no time is just a string that has to be before the number in my array that I want to look for so I can apply my function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look for indexes of `time (4)` and `time(8)` but using the `myarray.index()` from there make the changes in the strings included into those limits

```
myarray = ["time (1)","the text to replace ","time (2)","the text to replace ","time (3)","the text to replace ","time (4)","the text to replace ","time (5)","the text to replace ","time (6)","the text to replace ","time (7)","the text to replace ","time (8)","the text to replace ","time (9)","the text to replace ","time (10)","the text to replace "] 

def myfunc(myarray, fromtime, totime):
    original_string , replace_string = 'text', 'string'
    start_index = myarray.index("time ({})".format(fromtime))
    end_index = myarray.index("time ({})".format(totime)) + 2 # + 2 because you want to also change value for the outbound limit
    myarray[start_index : end_index] = [value if idx%2 == 0 else value.replace(original_string, replace_string) for idx, value in enumerate(myarray[start_index : end_index]) ]
    return myarray

myfunc(myarray, 4,8)
```

**Output**

```
['time (1)',
 'the text to replace ',
 'time (2)',
 'the text to replace ',
 'time (3)',
 'the text to replace ',
 'time (4)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (5)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (6)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (7)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (8)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (9)',
 'the text to replace ',
 'time (10)',
 'the text to replace ']
```

Comment: Can you join me here: chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195177/maya

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that myarray has the given format, you could write something like:

```
def myfunc (fromtime, totime):
    i = fromtime*2 - 1
    while i <= (totime*2 - 1):
        myarray[i] = myarray[i].replace('text', 'string')
        i+=2
```

Output of `myfunc(4, 8)`  is:

```
['time (1)',
 'the text to replace ',
 'time (2)',
 'the text to replace ',
 'time (3)',
 'the text to replace ',
 'time (4)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (5)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (6)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (7)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (8)',
 'the string to replace ',
 'time (9)',
 'the text to replace ',
 'time (10)',
 'the text to replace ']
```

Is this what you are after?